# In a Multiple Select Question, there are 4 options of which one or more can be correct. What is the cardinality of E?

Tags: permutations

In a Multiple Select Question, there are 4 options of which one or more can be correct. Let us define an event E that the option ‘A’ is correct. What is the cardinality of E?

MSQ Options are $= {A, B, C, D}

1. $n(E1)= \{ A \}$ is $1$ Only $A$ is the correct answer
2. $n(E2)= \{A, B\}$ is $2$ $A$ and $B$ are the correct answers
3. $n(E3)= \{A, C\}$ is $2$ $A$ and $C$ are the correct answers
4. $n(E4)= \{A, D\}$ is $2$ $A$ and $D$ are the correct answers
5. $n(E5)= \{A, B, C\}$ is $3$ $A$, $B$ and $C$ are the correct answers
6. $n(E6)= \{A, B, D\}$ is $3$ $A$, $B$ and $D$ are the correct answers
7. $n(E7)= \{A, C, D\}$ is $3$ $A$, $C$ and $D$ are the correct answers
8. $n(E8)= \{A, B, C, D\}$ is $4$ all options are the correct answers

Is this the answer? $=>$ The cardinality of $E$ is $=1+2+2+2+3+3+3+4 => 17$

I think the correct answer is $n(E)=\{\{ A \}, \{A, B\},\{A, C\},\{A, D\}, \{A, B, C\}, \{A, B, D\},\{A, B, C, D\}\} => 8$

Please correct me if I'm wrong about correct answer.

Comment: More simply:  each of the three other options, $\{B,C,D\}$ can (in principle) be either true or false independently of each other.  There are $8$ ways to assign truth values to this triple.

Comment: To be clear, $\{\color{red}{a},\color{blue}{b},\{c,d,e,f\}\}$ is of cardinality $3$... you have the red thing, you have the blue thing, and you have the black *thing*.  Just because that black "*thing*" happened to be a set with additional elements inside of it does not matter.  We do not "*flatten*" the set first before asking about its cardinality.  In the same way, each of your eight outcomes contribute only *one* to the overall size of $E$.